# Java input input decimals and deal with imaginary numbers

Tags: java

I want to make a quadratic formula program. I succeeded with the basics but have 2 major errors. One when I try to input decimal values as a,b or, c and the other when I have to deal with i(imaginary numbers). How do I fix these issues? I also appreciate ways to simplify the code here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Input a");
    Scanner ai = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = ai.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input b");
    Scanner bi = new Scanner(System.in);
    double b = bi.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input c");
    Scanner ci = new Scanner(System.in);
    double c = ci.nextInt();
    double Square1 = Math.pow(b, 2);
    double Square2 = -4*a*c;
    double Square3 = Square1 + Square2;
    double Square = Math.sqrt(Square3); 
    double Bottom = 2*a;
    double Top1 = -b + Square;
    double x1 = Top1/Bottom;
    double Top2 = -b - Square;
    double x2 = Top2/Bottom;
    System.out.printf("X = %s", x1);
    System.out.printf("X = %s", x2);

    }
}
```

Comment: What all those errors?

Comment: "double xx = nextInt()" double/int.. Do you need `nextDouble()`? For the imaginary part, you might want to use an `if` to check if `Square3` is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error you got because you have used method nextInt(). It throws InputMismatchException when you try read double - [Method nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Instead nextInt() you should use method nextDouble.

Second error: Java does not have support for imaginary numbers :(

If you want use imaginary numbers you have to write your class ImaginaryNumber.

This is your code refactored:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input a");
        double a = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input b");
        double b = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input c");
        double c = input.nextDouble();

        double square1 = Math.pow(b, 2);
        double square2 = -4 * a * c;
        double square3 = square1 + square2;

        if (square3 < 0) {
            double square = Math.sqrt(square3);

            double bottom = 2 * a;
            double top1 = -b + square;
            double x1 = top1 / bottom;
            double top2 = -b - square;
            double x2 = top2 / bottom;

            System.out.printf("X = %s", x1);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("X = %s", x2);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Can not calculate square root for negative number");
        }

        input.close();

    }
}
```

You can notice that I added

```
if (square3 < 0) {
```

that is because method Math.square can only take positive.
If you pass negative number it will return NaN - Not a number:
[Math.sqrt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)

Comment: Does OP want the imaginary/complex roots calculated, or is an error message okay?

Comment: I actually wanted the complex numbers calculated.

Comment: @DarkAriel7 In that case you should either write your class for imaginary numbers or use some library. I found this [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html))